# Storing database information into EOS

Tags: database, storage

I have a bunch of user data and I want to store it in the EOS blockchain. Each user data doesn't exceed 1kb. At most it is just: name, phone, email, btc address, and btc private key (encrypted).

I currently have this data in mysql database and I'd like to migrate it to EOS.

- Do I use memo field or some other type of eos storage to save this data?
- How do I retrieve it using public api's? What program do I use? Examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **Don't store personal information like email-addresses or phone-numbers on a public blockchain !!!**
2. The memo-field itself has nothing to do with the type of storage as it's just an action-parameter of type string which doesn't say anything about the type of storage used.
3. Please follow the [Data Persistence , Address-Book-Tutorial](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/data-persistence). It will also teach you the difference between the different storage-variants and how a *typical* memo-field works. Choosing the right type of storage for your application depends on the use-case and application-architecture.
4. There are several different ways to receive the data - public rpc-endpoints, [dfuse](https://www.dfuse.io/en), [openapi](https://eospark.com/openapi), running your own node etc. What to choose depends on the use-case and your application-architecture.

Comment: Your first point is crucial! In addition this thread [Is It safe to Store User keys on local db server?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/2165/is-it-safe-to-store-user-keys-on-local-db-server/2169#2169) may help.

Comment: Is there an example database I can query from a public api endpoint? say I created and deployed this database contract on eosio, how do i query it from a public block explorer?

Comment: @Patoshiパトシ pls do some research on your own. Here's one possible RPC-Endpoint to query state-data from an eosio-chain: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference#get_table_rows